# Import monadic stuff from another module

Tags: haskell

I have the following module structure:

Module A:

```hs
module ModuleA where

newtype Parser p = P (String -> Maybe (p, String))

parse :: Parser p -> String -> Maybe (p, String)
parse (P p) = p

item :: Parser Char
item = P (\inp -> case inp of
                 [] -> Nothing
                 (x: xs) -> Just (x, xs))
```

Module B:

```hs
module ModuleB where

...

instance Alternative Parser where
    empty = P (\inp -> Nothing)
    (P a) <|> (P b) = P (\inp -> case a inp of
                                 Nothing -> b inp
                                 Just (x, v) -> Just (x, v)
                        )
```

Module C:

```hs
module ModuleC where

import ModuleA
import ModuleB
import Data.Char


conditionalParser :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
conditionalParser f = do
                                x <- item
                                if f x then return x else empty
```

The code does not compile, with error `Variable not in scope: empty :: Parser Char`. If I move the `Alternative` instance into the `ModuleC` module, it compiles.

How can I import the `Alternative` instance definition, so that it can be safely used? I have also tried using a qualified reference for `empty`, with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing the instance definition from `ModuleB` just fine. It's the *class* definition that you're not importing, and it's in the *class*, not the instance, that the `empty` method is declared.

Add this at the top of `ModuleC`:

```
import Control.Applicative
```

That should do it.

Or, alternatively, you can re-export the `Applicative` class from `ModuleB`.

---

Note also that it's generally considered unsound to define instances in a module separate from both the type and the class. This may lead to subtle unexpected results with choosing the right instance down the line. This is called "orphan instance" and there is even a compiler warming against it.